# Proguard tutorial

Tags: android, android-proguard

Can anyone give me a good tutorial for learning Proguard configuration?
When I set minifyEnabled as true in my gradle file, I got a lot of warnings and errors.

Below is the log.

```
> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease] Warning:Dependency
> org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1 is ignored for debug as it
> may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android. In
> case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class
> packages Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1
> is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal
> version provided by Android. In case of problem, please repackage it
> with jarjar to change the class packages :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkReleaseManifest
> :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers133Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta113Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics252Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore235Library
> UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComEtsyAndroidGridLibrary105Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk410Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComGithubGabrielemariottiCardsCardslibCards201Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComGithubGabrielemariottiCardsCardslibCore201Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComGithubGabrielemariottiCardsCardslibExtraDragdrop201Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComGithubGabrielemariottiCardsCardslibExtraStaggeredgrid201Library
> UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareComGithubGabrielemariottiCardsCardslibRecyclerview201Library
> UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library
> UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComMcxiaokeVolleyLibraryAar100Library
> UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComSothreeSlidinguppanelLibrary204Library
> UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric137Library UP-TO-DATE
> :app:prepareReleaseDependencies :app:compileReleaseAidl
> :app:compileReleaseRenderscript :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> :app:generateReleaseResValues :app:generateReleaseResources
> :app:mergeReleaseResources AAPT err(873970199): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\enter_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\push_switch_off.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(873970199): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\watch_number_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\facebook_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(873970199): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\icon_rumour.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\pop_profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(873970199): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon_review.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\watch_eye.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(873970199): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\pop_cross_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\marked_star.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(873970199): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\push_switch_off.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\enter_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(873970199): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\enter_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\upcomers_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1854121906): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\back.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(640927137): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\red_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(640927137): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\push_switch_off.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(640927137): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(640927137): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\profile_pic.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1429391180): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\google_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(153582744): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\upcomers_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1429391180): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\profile_pic.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(153582744): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\add_more_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1429391180): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\push_switch_on.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(153582744): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\logout_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(153582744): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\bg.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(153582744): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\google_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(153582744): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\gray_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1429391180): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\pop_cross_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1429391180): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\icon_rumour.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(500068536): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\profile_pic.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(500068536): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\marked_star.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(500068536): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\marked_star.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(500068536): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\watch_eye.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(500068536): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\member.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1979267756): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\pop_profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1979267756): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\google_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1979267756): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\pop_delete_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1979267756): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1979267756): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\pop_profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1979267756): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\upcomers_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(421466382): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\watch_number_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(421466382): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\upcomers_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(421466382): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\pop_not_now_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(421466382): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\feedback_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(421466382): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\green_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(421466382): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\icon_rumour.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(421466382): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon_news_update.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\member.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\unmarked_star.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\facebook_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\unmarked_star.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\watch_number_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon_rumour.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\gray_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\push_switch_on.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\green_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\feedback_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\pop_cross_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1126743397): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\icon_review.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1698686763): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\pop_delete_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1698686763): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\green_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1698686763): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\push_switch_on.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1698686763): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\icon_review.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1698686763): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\red_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1698686763): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\readmore.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1207863721): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\unmarked_star.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1207863721): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\facebook_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1207863721): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1207863721): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\red_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1207863721): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\welcome_logo.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(2147243758): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\watch_eye.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(2147243758): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\feedback_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(2147243758): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\enter_arrow.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1130059881): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\logout_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1130059881): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\welcome_logo.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1130059881): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\welcome_logo.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1130059881): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\logout_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(62460143): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\gray_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(62460143): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\red_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(62460143): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\bg.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(62460143): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\bg.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1833151080): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\icon_news_update.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1833151080): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\welcome_logo.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1833151080): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\unmarked_star.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1833151080): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\google_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\logout_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\pop_profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\watch_eye.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\member.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\explore_active.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\icon_news_update.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\push_switch_on.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\pop_not_now_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\feedback_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\watch_number_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1349674962): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\add_more_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(203120028): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\readmore.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(203120028): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\facebook_login.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(203120028): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\member.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(203120028): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\readmore.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(203120028): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\pop_not_now_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(203120028): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\pop_not_now_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(203120028): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\profile_pic.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1303134337): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\pop_delete_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1303134337): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\profile_icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1303134337): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\add_more_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1303134337): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\push_switch_off.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1303134337): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\add_more_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1303134337): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\green_button.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited AAPT err(1303134337): F:\Android\Upcomer
> Project\Upcomer---Android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\icon_news_update.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
```

I am not able to add the whole log as stack overflow has size limitation.

Comment: `minifyEnabled false`

Comment: 1st off, you are using a number of external libraries there - check their docs, as they may have specific proguard rules themselves...

Comment: I know. If I set minifyEnabled to false, these errors will be gone. But I have read that using proguard is good to compress the code and make the code unreadable if someone tries to decompile the apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Basic knowledge :

```
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html
```

Key and attriubtes  knowledge for android you can browse other data also on this site

```
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#application
```

Also when you includes the third party library and jar file make sure on their site they generally provided the code for the proguard when using that library add that on your config file

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Sandy :)